# Travelling with expired Pakistani passport

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, pakistan

One of my friend has an expired passport of Pakistan and living in UK. How will he be travelling back to Pakistan? Any letter he needs as renewing passport will take long time and he wants to travel soon. Any suggestion please.

Comment: He will not be able to travel to Pakistan without a passport or another travel document/letter issued by the consulate of Pakistan.

Comment: There is no way to know. The last immigration authorities to stop him,
Maybe, it is not on the plane.

Answer (score 8):

Your friend's only course of action is to apply for a new passport (or perhaps another [emergency travel document](http://www.phclondon.org/consular/traveldocument/)) at the High Commission or a consulate of Pakistan.  If it takes too long for your friend's travel plans, there is not much to be done.

Renewal shouldn't take that long.  According to the website of the High Commission, regular applications are processed in 20 days, and urgent applications, the surcharge for which is just £20 unless the passport was lost or stolen, take 10 days: http://www.phclondon.org/mrp/fees/

Answer (score 2):

There's absolutely no way. Latest the immigration authority would stop him, he will probably not even be let on the plane.

Answer (score 0):

He cannot travel on an expired passport. He will not even get a boarding card from the airline when checking in (first time he has to show his passport).

Comment: That's up to the rules of the destination country, which the airline will check at check-in. In this case you're right, but for instance a UK citizen can enter the UK on an expired UK passport.