# Pakistani Passport expiring 4 months after traveling from US to Pakistan - Can I renew my passport in Pakistan?

Tags: usa, passports, pakistan, us-residents

I have a Pakistani Passport which is expiring at the end of July and I am traveling from USA to Pakistan at the end of March (validity of around 4 months). I have a Green Card as well.

Will they allow me to board the plane ? I have plans to renew the passport in Pakistan.

Comment: You may know that as a green card holder you can enter the US without a passport, though you might need a new passport to leave Pakistan.

Answer (score 5):

There are no exit formalities in the US.

You can safely travel, and renew your passport while in Pakistan. Your passport is valid until midnight of the date of expiry.

If you have any valid visas on your old passport, it will be returned to you along with your new passport; the old passport is no longer valid for travel - but will only be used to show any endorsements (visas or other stamps) to immigration authorities.

You should make sure you ask for expedited passport renewal (it takes around a week) vs the normal month or so.

Here are the requirements:

1. NADRA (digital) ID
2. NADRA (digital) ID copy
3. Old Passport + its copy

The fee depends on how long and how many pages you want on your passport; and it is deposited at a bank:

- For 5 year validity:

  1. 3000 Rupees normal / 5000 Rupees Urgent (36 pages)
  2. 5500 Rupees normal / 9000 Rupees Urgent (72 pages)
  3. 6000 Rupees normal / 10000 Rupees Urgent (100 pages)
- For 10 year validity:

  1. 5400 Rupees normal / 9000 Rupees Urgent (36 pages)
  2. 9900 Rupees normal / 16200 Rupees Urgent (72 pages)
  3. 10800 Rupees normal / 21600 Rupees Urgent (100 pages)

You can find the location of nearest office for passports [online](http://www.dgip.gov.pk/Files/Offices.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You can return to your home country which issued your passport at any time, [up to the date of expiration](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&HEALTH=1&VISA=1&NA=PK&AR=US&EM=US&DE=PK&PASSTYPES=PASS&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C) of your passport. It does not need to be valid for any amount of time after your arrival in your home country.

Remember, when you renew your passport, if you have valid visas in your old passport, ask for it to be returned so that you can continue to use those visas.

Comment: For some countries (the UK, at least), you can return even after the expiration date of the passport.

Comment: @phoog This is true, but [Pakistan is not such a country](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/51782/3221).

Comment: I don't doubt it! I commented only because of your general statement, not because of any suspicion that Pakistan shares this property with the UK.  The question you link to, however, and its answers, contain no discussion of Pakistan's willingness to admit its citizens who present expired passports.